# java.sql.SQLException: SQL string is not Query in glassfish server

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, glassfish, ojdbc

we have used `executeQuery()` for deleting the data in a table using java code.It is able to delete properly when we run the program using Eclipse, but while build the sources and deployed in glassfish server am getting error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: SQL string is not Query
```

Means, we should not use `executeQuery()` for DML operations.If that is the case it should not even work in eclipse.

Below is my code:

```
PreparedStatement deletePreparedStmt = null;

String sql = "DELETE FROM emp WHERE eno = ?";

try

{

    deletePreparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    deletePreparedStmt.setInt(1,50);

    deletePreparedStmt.executeQuery();

    con.commit();

}

catch(Exception e)

{

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Can anyone clarify it?

Comment: It will be better if you post your code in qusetion

Comment: executeQuery() expects a select statement. Use executeUpdate().

Comment: Yes I know.I will use.But why is it working in eclipse then?

Comment: It's not working in Eclipse. It's the driver that makes the decision, so either you're using a non-standard driver in Eclipse, your environment is completely different, or you're just confused and *think* it's working in Eclipse.

Comment: Yes.it is not eclipse responsibility, it is entirely related with drivers only.I have used same driver jar which is being used in glassfish server.

Comment: try this : String sql = "DELETE FROM emp WHERE eno = 50";

Comment: I am bothering about the difference not about how to fix it.

Comment: No half decent driver would let that fly, so if you still think that it's "working in Eclipse", you're just plain wrong and wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish server internally having ojdbc7dms.jar, which is not allowing executeQuery() method for DML operations.
Because of that only we are getting

java.sql.SQLException: SQL string is not Query Exception